# How to create a form for a model which embeds a model that inherits two children in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a form for one of my models named Property which embeds another model named LateFeePolicy.

```
class Property
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps

   embeds_one :late_fee_policy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :late_fee_policy
end
```

LateFeePolicy is parent of two child classes:

```
class FixedLateFeePolicy < LateFeePolicy
   field :amount, type: Money
end
```

and

```
class PercentageLateFeePolicy < LateFeePolicy
   field :percentage, type: Float
end
```

The question is how can I dynamically generate a form for creating an instance of Property and choosing between Fixed or Percentage late fee policy.

This is my form, but after opening it shows me nothing:

```
<%= form_for @property, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
   <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :late_fee_policy, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
         <%= f.fields_for :late_fee_policy do |flfp| %>
             <div><%= flfp.label :amount %>
             <%= flfp.text_field :amount %></div>
         <% end %>
      </div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an attribute to the `Property` model to specify which type it is and represent that as a radio button and base on the radio button show or hide the correct field.  I could be misunderstanding your question though. [Checkout RailsCasts Nested Forms Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), it goes over dynamic field additions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, You understood me correctly :)
I used "if else" in my erb file to determine the type of late fee instance and according to that generated my form.